# Django swappable model foreign keys

Tags: python, django, django-models

Suppose I have a reusable app, that defines a model `Person` and a model `Invite.`

A `Person` has a `OneToOne` field to `AUTH_USER_MODEL` and defines some basic fields (such as birthday). It is a swappable model, so that a project which uses this app can easily add other fields (such as gender, etc.)

In my reusable app, I define a setting that provides the swapping model (otherwise, a default one will be used, exactly as `django.contrib.auth` does it.

The Invite model has a `OneToOneField` to the swappable `Person` model and an email field. (I think, it's quite clear what this model is for). The model itself is swappable as well, but I don't think that this makes any difference for the kind of problem I am facing.

reusable app models:

```py
class AbstractPerson(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='person')
    
    birthdate = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Person(AbstractPerson):
    class Meta(AbstractPerson.Meta):  
        swappable = 'REUSABLEAPP_PERSON_MODEL'

class AbstractInvite(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    person = models.OneToOneField(settings.REUSABLEAPP_PERSON_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, related_name='+')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Invite(AbstractInvite):
    class Meta(AbstractInvite.Meta):
        swappable = 'REUSABLEAPP_INVITE_MODEL'
```

If I create the initial migration for my reusable app (using a dummy project and not swapping out my models), I get the following migration for my reusable app:

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Person',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('birthdate', models.DateField()),
                ('user', models.OneToOneField(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, related_name='person', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
                'swappable': 'REUSABLEAPP_PERSON_MODEL',
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Invite',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('email', models.EmailField(max_length=254)),
                ('person', models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='+', to=settings.REUSABLEAPP_PERSON_MODEL)),
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
                'swappable': 'REUSABLEAPP_INVITE_MODEL',
            },
        ),
    ]
```

If I then include my reusable app in another project, and swap out the `Person` and `Invite` model, I get an error when running `makemigrations`:

> ValueError: The field myreusable_app.Invite.person was declared with a lazy reference to 'tester.myperson', but app 'tester' isn't installed.

(`tester` is the app that defines the swapped models, obviously)

If I delete the migration from my reusable app, and run makemigrations again, it works. the created migration is almost identical to the one above, with the exception of a new dependency:

```py
migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.REUSABLEAPP_PERSON_MODEL),
```

The migration created in the `tester` app looks as follows:

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='MyPerson',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('birthdate', models.DateField()),
                ('user', models.OneToOneField(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, related_name='person', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='MyInvite',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('email', models.EmailField(max_length=254)),
                ('person', models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='+', to=settings.REUSABLEAPP_PERSON_MODEL)),
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
            },
        ),
    ]
```

I have looked up what `swappable_dependency` actually does: It looks **only** which app name is defined (let's say, the setting is `tester.mymodel`), and creates a dependency to this apps *initial* migration.

Now, if I **delete** the created migration from my `tester` app, I cannot run `makemigrations` again, I get the same error as above.

**To clarify up until this point: Everything works as desired, *if* I delete the initial migration (and therefore all future migrations!) from my reusable app.**

The problem, as I understand it, is the following:
The reusable app has a dependency to the initial migration of the client application that defines the swapped models. But this migration does not exist yet (heck, I am trying to create it!), so `makemigration` failes. (running `makemigrations tester` does not help).
But this almost exact same thing works flawlessly when swapping out the standard `User` model for a custom one. Furthermore, I do not fully understand why the error message states that the `tester` app is *not installed*. It definitly is inside my `INSTALLED_APPS` and it is picked up by the django-ecosystem.

After a few hours, I came up with a possible (but hacky) workaround:

1. Remove my reusable app from `INSTALLED_APPS`
2. Create `MyInvite` and `MyPerson` in the `tester` app (they both inherit from `django.models.Model`
3. Create those models by running `makemigrations tester`
4. Add my reusable app to `INSTALLED_APPS`
5. Define the swap settings
6. Change the inheritance of my models to their respective abstract counterparts
7. Run `makemigrations` again.

This works, because the `initial` migration of my reusable app now can fullfill the dependency to the swapped models by looking at the initial migration of `tester` that defines the models with the same name that is defined in the swap variables.
But I am sure that there must be a better way to do that.

This leaves me with the following questions:

**How can I handle foreign key relationships to swapped models?**

**Why can't I create migrations for one app without looking at the migrations of other apps?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I have to answer my own question.

[This](https://github.com/openwisp/django-swappable-models) package provides a public interface to the swapping API. I have learned, that looking at closed issues is sometimes more helpful than reading the open ones.

Especially [#12](https://github.com/openwisp/django-swappable-models/issues/12), and the open [#10](https://github.com/openwisp/django-swappable-models/issues/10) answer my question. To sum it up, what works for the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting, does not work for any other swappable model, because the `lazy_reference` error is **ignored**, when the target model is set as `AUTH_USER_MODEL` within django, [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/migrations/state.py#L564):

```py
# There shouldn't be any operations pending at this point.
from django.core.checks.model_checks import _check_lazy_references
ignore = {make_model_tuple(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)} if ignore_swappable else set()
errors = _check_lazy_references(self, ignore=ignore)
if errors:
   raise ValueError("\n".join(error.msg for error in errors))
```

The proposed solution would be a registry, where all swapped models are registered and then looked up, to ignore the lazy reference error. Unfortunately, there seems to be no plans from the django devs to support this, as I have not found any open issues or feature requests for that.